# Customize OData xml with new namespace

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm using WCF Data services.

The default feed property for an entity in my OData service is

```
<feed xml:base="http://localhost:54527/DataModel.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

How can I add my own name spaces to this list in the feed property?

I'm trying to make my odata service GeoRSS compatible, I've added some EntityPropertyMappingAttribute's to make the data compatible, but it isn't being recognised by the tool we're using.

Right now it's producing this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://localhost:54527/DataModel.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Collars</title>
  <id>http://localhost:54527/DataModel.svc/Collars</id>
  <updated>2011-11-07T09:23:05Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Collars" href="Collars" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://localhost:54527/DataModel.svc/Collars(HOLEID='ABL001',PROJECTCODE='ACA')</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2011-11-07T09:23:05Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Collar" href="Collars(HOLEID='ABL001',PROJECTCODE='ACA')" />
    <category term="Neo.Collar" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:HOLEID>ABL001</d:HOLEID>
        <d:PROJECTCODE>ACA</d:PROJECTCODE>
        <d:TENEMENTID>5853</d:TENEMENTID>
        <d:LAT>116.49531406</d:LAT>
        <d:LONG>-21.65159678</d:LONG>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
    <geo:lat xmlns:geo="http://www.georss.org/georss">116.49531406</geo:lat>
    <geo:long xmlns:geo="http://www.georss.org/georss">-21.65159678</geo:long>
  </entry>
```

But I would rather have the geo namespace up the top:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://localhost:54527/DataModel.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:geo="http://www.georss.org/georss">
  <title type="text">Collars</title>
  <id>http://localhost:54527/DataModel.svc/Collars</id>
  <updated>2011-11-07T09:23:05Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Collars" href="Collars" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://localhost:54527/DataModel.svc/Collars(HOLEID='ABL001',PROJECTCODE='ACA')</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2011-11-07T09:23:05Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Collar" href="Collars(HOLEID='ABL001',PROJECTCODE='ACA')" />
    <category term="Neo.Collar" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:HOLEID>ABL001</d:HOLEID>
        <d:PROJECTCODE>ACA</d:PROJECTCODE>
        <d:TENEMENTID>5853</d:TENEMENTID>
        <d:LAT>116.49531406</d:LAT>
        <d:LONG>-21.65159678</d:LONG>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
    <geo:lat>116.49531406</geo:lat>
    <geo:long>-21.65159678</geo:long>
  </entry>
```

I might be going about this completely the wrong way.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to add namespace? That has meaning only if namespace is used which means changing serialization and in such case all used namespaces will be included automatically.

Comment: Added some more detail for what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: For example this OData source does exactly what I'm trying to achieve with respect to the namespace for geo rss and it is able to be consumed by the geo rss tool we are using. http://www.commuterapi.com/Wiki/developer-resources and http://transit.cloudapp.net/DevTransitODataService.svc/Stops

Comment: Well. I see the difference but in respect to XML specifications those two representations are exactly same and each valid XML parser must work with both of them in exactly same way. Because of that I'm not sure if there is any way to change it - even if it is possible it will most probably be complex change.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's the fault of the tool which can't read the xml, which is unfortunately something I cannot change.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's no way in WCF Data Services to do this. The Entity Property Mapping works locally (on the element it maps to), there's no ability for it to specify that some namespaces should be declared up front.